# Vlookup based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

The data I have in my "entity sheet"

| entity id | source id | source entity id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR0001 | GOP | 1200 |
| HR0002 | WSS | WSS1201 |
| HR0003 | GOP | 1201 |
| HR0004 | WSS-T | WSST1202 |
| HR0005 | GOP | 1202 |
| HR0006 | GOP | 1203 |
| HR0007 | WSS-S | WSSS1203 |
| HR0008 | GOP | 1204 |
| HR0009 | GOP | 1205 |
| HR0010 | GOP | 1206 |
| HR0011 | WSS-R | WSSR1204 |
| HR0012 | WSS-T | WSST1205 |
| HR0013 | WSS-S | WSSS1206 |
| HR0014 | GOP | 1207 |
| HR0015 | WSS-T | WSSS1207 |
| HR0006 | WSS-S | WSSS1208 |
| HR0007 | GOP | 1208 |
| HR0008 | WSS-R | WSST1209 |
| HR0009 | WSS-S | WSSS1210 |

In my working sheet, I need the source entity id (column c) data, by doing a VLOOKUP on the entity id (column A), based on source id (column b). that is I need only those beginning with "WS" IDs on my working sheet. My code is

```
Sub Test()
    Worksheets("working sheet").Activate
    Dim sht, sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, LR As Long
        
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("working sheet")
    Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("entity sheet")
    
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      
        With sht
        For i = 2 To LR
            If InStr(sht1.Range("B" & i).Value, "WS") Then
                sht.Range("B" & i).Value = (Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & i).Value, Worksheets("entity sheet").Range("A2:C5000"), 3, False))
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

desired result - in the working sheet

| entity id | source entity id - WSS |
| --- | --- |
| HR0001 |  |
| HR0002 | WSS1201 |
| HR0003 |  |
| HR0004 | WSST1202 |
| HR0005 |  |
| HR0006 | WSSS1208 |
| HR0007 | WSSS1203 |
| HR0008 | WSST1209 |
| HR0009 | WSSS1210 |
| HR0010 |  |
| HR0011 | WSSR1204 |
| HR0012 | WSST1205 |
| HR0013 | WSSS1206 |
| HR0014 |  |
| HR0015 | WSSS1207 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: @PEH Have added my code

Comment: Please insert your sample data, not as an image, but as a table. Copy some sample data in Excel, goto https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables, paste the data into the webpage (**File** -> **Paste table data...**), click on **Generate**, click on **Copy to clipboard**; then edit the data into your question.

Comment: Also please include the results you are looking for as a table as well.

Comment: What is the problem you're having with your code? Also, from what I can tell, it seems to me that you could probably achieve this with formulas instead of VBA.

Comment: @user2574 you mean the VLOOKUP returns the value in column A? From what I can see, the VLOOKUP looks okay. Can you please show us what the final result should look like? It takes time to analyze and write up solutions to questions, and no one wants to spend this time answering the wrong question through misunderstanding.

Comment: @stifin @ Zev Spitz - I have given the required inputs and the result i need. My vlookup code is not getting me the required result, it is returning the possible first value. To be more specific the code "If InStr(sht1.Range("B" & i).Value, "WS") Then" is not working. Help me on this please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a little while but... I've got two different versions for you: one with VBA and one with just formulas.

**With VBA**

The issue you had was that VLOOKUP returns the first match but you needed to satisfy *two* criteria (that is: (i) match on **entity id** and (ii) match on **source id** begins with "WS").

This meant that you either had to:

1. use a formula that could match both criteria at the same time, OR
2. find *all* matches with the first criteria (e.g. with FIND) and then loop through the results to match the second criteria -- probably something like this: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/21/find-all-instances-with-vba

I selected option #1 as I expected it would make the code shorter.

To do this, I took advantage of a trick I've used in formulas before where I can use "&" between two ranges to match on *two criteria* at the same time. So, instead of matching "HR0012" first and then "WS-something" second, I match "HR0012WS-something" at once. (You can view this concept by pasting `=A2:A20&B2:B20` in an empty *column* somewhere in your **entity** sheet.)

The following code assumes that your active worksheet is your **working** sheet. Paste this code behind your **working** sheet, then run it when you have that sheet open. [image: animated gif]

```
Public Sub tester()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim sSourceEntityId As String

    For Each rg In Range("A2:A16")
        sSourceEntityId = Evaluate("=XLOOKUP(""" & rg.Value & "WS"",entity!A2:A20&LEFT(entity!B2:B20,2),entity!C2:C20,"""",0,1)")
        If Len(sSourceEntityId) > 0 Then
            rg.Offset(0, 1).Value = sSourceEntityId
        End If
    Next rg
End Sub
```

If the part inside the `Evaluate` is not clear, paste

```
=XLOOKUP(A1&"WS",entity!A2:A20&LEFT(entity!B2:B20,2),entity!C2:C20,"",0,1)
```

somewhere inside your working sheet to see it more clearly.

Also, note that you used `Instr`, which would find "WS" *anywhere* in the string. I used `LEFT(value, 2)="WS"` to be sure that I matched only the first 2 characters.

I also had to use `XLOOKUP` instead of `VLOOKUP` to allow me to use the `LEFT(value, 2)`. If you're using an old version of Excel, you won't have XLOOKUP, unfortunately.

**Without VBA**

Paste this formula into A2 on your **working** sheet:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(entity!$C$2:$C$20,AGGREGATE(15,3,((entity!$A$2:$A$20&LEFT(entity!$B$2:$B$20,2)=A2&"WS")/(entity!$A$2:$A$20&LEFT(entity!$B$2:$B$20,2)=A2&"WS"))*ROW(entity!$A$2:$A$20)-ROW(entity!$A$1),1)),"")
```

Then copy that formula down to every row that you want to do a match on. Just to be clearer, it will look like this: [image: formula-based approach]

This is a little complex. I based it on an approach in this [article](https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/), which explains step-by-step how to use `INDEX(.. AGGREGATE(..))` for multiple matches. Although it's pretty neat how it works, you may prefer the VBA approach as it is probably easier to maintain.

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that there is a possibility that the IFERROR() in the formula *may* slow your spreadsheet down if you have many matches and rows. I also created a version of the formula that doesn't use IFERROR. It uses an IF to first check if there are any `TRUE` matches first before executing the `INDEX.. AGGREGATE`. You may not need it, but I've pasted it below just in case it's useful:

```
=IF(MAX(INT(entity!$A$2:$A$20&LEFT(entity!$B$2:$B$20,2)=A2&"WS"))=1,INDEX(entity!$C$2:$C$20,AGGREGATE(15,3,((entity!$A$2:$A$20&LEFT(entity!$B$2:$B$20,2)=A2&"WS")/(entity!$A$2:$A$20&LEFT(entity!$B$2:$B$20,2)=A2&"WS"))*ROW(entity!$A$2:$A$20)-ROW(entity!$A$1),1)),"")
```

UPDATE 2:

The statement used in the VBA Evaluate will also work directly as a formula and is much simpler to understand. I realized this when I realized that a single valid match is okay (i.e. we don't need multiple matches):

```
=XLOOKUP(A2&"WS",entity!$A$2:$A$20&LEFT(entity!$B$2:$B$20,2),entity!$C$2:$C$20,"",0,1)
```

Comment: @ stifin - Thank you. Appreciate your help. The VBA code is working fine. But I want the desired result in another sheet called "working sheet". How do i get this done ? This is for a report that i generate everyday, so VBA code is more effective.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the VBA code assumes that your active worksheet is your working sheet. Paste the VBA code behind your **working** sheet, not your **entity** sheet, and make sure that your active sheet is **working** sheet when you run it

Comment: `Dim shtwkng As Worksheet 
Set shtwkng = Worksheets("working") 
shtwkng.Activate`

@ stifin - I added these to the code that you wrote, but it is still returning the first found value.

Comment: You don't need that. Just make sure your working sheet is already active when you run the macro. See animated gif I added to the answer.

Comment: Make sure you pasted the code **to your working sheet**. If you paste the code to the wrong sheet, it will probably not work or it may even ruin another sheet

Comment: @ stifin - Yes I pasted to the working sheet.  Did just as yours. But am not getting the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229797/discussion-between-stifin-and-user2574).